# Mysql database insert with user input variable

Tags: php, mysql

The below code entered into the database:

```
"INSERT INTO customer_order (price) VALUES (1)";
```

Instead of `VALUES (1)`, however, I want the value to be determined by user input.

Like this:

```
"INSERT INTO customer_order (customer_id) VALUES (".$edit_type.")";
```

This does not work, however, and does not return an error.

Comment: shows us your customer_order Table structure, check whether  cutomer_id Auto Increment

Comment: Please provide a self-contained code snippet showing your issue, as well as information on your DB schema. This works fine under plenty of circumstances.

Comment: Never mind guys after hours of searching (an of course as soon as i post a question) i notices it was a data type error i made.

Answer (score -1):

here you are using double code inside double code

try this :

```
"INSERT INTO customer_order (customer_id) VALUES ($edit_type)";
```

Comment: Note the period, that's PHP's concatenation operator. His code compiles fine and runs as expected.

Comment: It's just a concatenation. It will not give error on his sql query